# When overloading methods in Java, where do you calculate additional parameter data?

Tags: java, parameters, overloading, optional-parameters

I often find myself in situations where I have a method signature like this:

```
public returnType doStuff(mandatoryParam, calculableParam1, calculableParam2);
```

In these situations I sometimes want to support these different method signatures:

```
public returnType doStuff(mandatoryParam);
public returnType doStuff(mandatory, calculable1); 
public returnType doStuff(mandatory, calculable2); 
public returnType doStuff(mandator, calculable1, calculable2);
```

When doing overloading like this, is it better to have the overloads pass null to the base method like this:

```
public returnType doStuff(mandatoryParam){
    doStuff(mandotryParam, null, null)
}

public returnType doSTuff(mandatoryParam, calculable1, calculable2){
    if(null == calculable1){
        calculable1 = calculate(); 
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Or is it better to calculate the calculable params and then pass them to the base method like this:

```
public returnType doStuff(mandatoryParam){
    Calculable calc1 = figureItOut1(); 
    Calculable calc2 = figureItOut2(); 
    doStuff(mandotryParam, calc1, calc2); 
}
```

Comment: It depends. Do you want your longer overloads to support null references, defaulting in the same way as the other ones?

Comment: Also, you definitely mean overloading rather than overriding as per your title.

Comment: Indeed. I definitely do mean overloading. Typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose the 2nd approach. The 1st approach gives more ways to do the same thing, which is an indication of redundancy in API.

In some cases though, there are too many parameters that should have default values, it's impractical to provide all overloaded versions, and it won't be beneficial to users anyway. Then there should only be one base method  which accepts null arguments as default values for the parameters.